# How can I transform to reported speech this: "As soon as it shall have been perfected, we would be pleased to receive it."?

Tags: reported-speech

> G. L. Gillespie, “Letter to R. M. Nevin”, Washington, DC, January 24,
> 1905.
>
> From: War Department, Board of Ordnance & Fortification.
>
> To: Hon. R. M. Nevin, House of Representatives, Washington, D.C.
>
> My dear Sir:- ...
>
> It appears from the letter of Messrs. Wilbur and
> Orville Wright that their machine has not yet been brought to the
> stage of practical operation, but as soon as it shall have been
> perfected, this Board would be pleased to receive further
> representations from them, in regard to it.
>
> Very respectfully, G. L. Gillespie, Major General, General Staff,
> President of the Board.

This is my try for reported speech but I am highly unsure about it:

Major General G. L. Gillespie answered that it appeared from the letter of the Wright brothers that their machine had not yet been brought to the stage of practical operation, but as soon as it **would have been
perfected (was perfected, had been perfected)**, the Board **would have been pleased (would be pleased)** to receive further representations from them, in regard to it.

Comment: Note that this letter itself is written in highly formal but also quite antiquated language. No-one would use "as soon as it shall have been X" today.

Comment: Do you already feel so confident with general topic of reported speech, that you would like to push the limits of possibility by translating an unusual, formal, antiquated text?

Comment: The problem is that I need the reported speech form of the answer the Wrights received from the War Department. Even an approximate representation would be perfect for me. I do not really want to make wrong guesses and finally write something that does not make sense in English. I believe that no matter how old a text, containing a direct speech is, a native speaker can find a reported speech equivalent for it, as long as the original text can be understood.

Comment: could be "was perfected", "would be pleased".